# MATLAB figure size wrong after create

Tags: matlab

When creating a window with MATLAB programmatically:

```
mainfigure = figure(...
    'Units','Pixels',...
    'Position',[5 40 1550 900]) % print to console to check
mainfigure % again just to be sure
```

... which is within the usable area of the monitor (horizontically from 0 to 1919 and vertically from 36 to 1800-something) the following SOMETIMES happens (with roughly 20% chance):

```
mainfigure = figure(...
    'Units','Pixels',...
    'Position',[5 40 1550 900])

mainfigure = 

  Figure (1) with properties:

      Number: 1
        Name: ''
       Color: [0.9400 0.9400 0.9400]
    Position: [5 40 1550 900]
       Units: 'pixels'

  Show all properties

>> mainfigure

mainfigure = 

  Figure (1) with properties:

      Number: 1
        Name: ''
       Color: [0.9400 0.9400 0.9400]
    Position: [2 36 1558 890]
       Units: 'pixels'

  Show all properties
```

Immediately after creation, window size is correct, but checking the created figure afterwards it seems that the figure received an incorrect size.

The exact incorrect size values presented by MATLAB (1558x890 origin 2,36) are always the same, but the actual size as seen on screen vary wildly.

Adding uicontrols to this figure afterwards fails spectacularly with controls being put all over the place including off of drawable area.

When printing said figure to PNG, the final image is indeed 1550x900 as intended, but areas not within both figure sizes (1550x900 and 1558x890) show either white or random data.

Has anyone come across this problem before or can anyone explain what is happening?

I am using MATLAB R2015a op CentOS 7.

**Edit:** this minimal test reproduces the error 100% of times:

```
mainfigure = figure(...
    'Units','Pixels',...
    'Position',[5 40 1550 900])
pause(0.5); % raises error chance from 20% to 100%
mainfigure
```

**Edit2:** and this manual test can create an array of randomly sized windows depending on pause time:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

for i = 1:10
    mainfigure = figure(...
        'Units','Pixels',...
        'Position',[15 45 1550 900]);
    pause(0.1); % needs to be at least 0.1, otherwise creates bunch of randomly sized windows
end
```

Comment: What does `get(0, 'MonitorPositions')` give you?

Comment: Two 1920x1080 monitors side by side: 1           1        1920        1080 (\n)
1921           1        1920        1080